# Use Carrierwave with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave, activeadmin

Did any of you guys manage to get Active Admin with Carrierwave working?

When I installed AA everything worked fine but the image file upload
fields were plain text fields so added following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Club do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Club" do
      f.input :league
      f.input :name
      f.input :image, :as => :file
      f.input :approved
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

Now it's displayed as a file upload field and I can select a file but
after I submitted the form nothing changed. There's still no image and
the image field is empty. Anyone knows what else to do to get it
working?

Comment: do you have attr_accessors in your model?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Finally found the problem.

```
form do |f|
```

needs to become:

```
form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
```

I still don't know why console is not working but well, at least I can upload new images now :) Thanks a lot for the help, bruno077!

Comment: Of course! how come I didn't think of that! Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works without an issue, remember to set the attr_accessible if you haven't. According to your configuration, you should have the following code in your model:

```
#app/models/club.rb

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible (previous list), :image #If exists
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

And of course you should have generated the Image uploader with

```
rails generate uploader image
```

Edit: you can follow [Ryan's railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads) if you have any issue. That's what I did for my ActiveAdmin app with Carrierwave

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I got all that already...

`class Club < ActiveRecord::Base`
`attr_accessible :name, :image, :photo_id, :league_id, :approved, :permalink`
`mount_uploader :image, IconUploader`

And I, of course, have an IconUploader which worked before I introduced ActiveAdmin. What else could be missing?

Sorry for the terrible formatting but it doesn't seem to like my carriage returns...

Comment: I just realized I can't even update the image attribute in the console, there must be something else wrong...

Comment: Does the image attribute appear in your schema.rb ? If it doesn't, you probably don't even have the attribute in the db

Comment: Yes, of course:   create_table "clubs", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "image" ...

Comment: Oh, by the way. Some clubs have a value in the image field but they were all created with the seeds command ("club1.image.store! ...")

Comment: I can't seem to grasp why you would even have an issue trying to update the image field from the console. Do you have any validation going on with this attribute? I would recommend you go step by step with the linked screencast, it worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: I did it step by step again already but since I can't even change the image field in the console anymore it doesn't really help. Like I said it all worked before I introduced ActiveAdmin... I guess I have to go back to before I installed it.